# Has some command that lists the privileges of a user in db2?

Tags: db2, permissions, users

I'm using db2 9.7 on linux and i want to list my privileges on database...
Ex: SYSADM, SECADM, DBADM, etc.
So, has some command in db2 that lists the privileges of a user in db2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the system catalog views.

Generally speaking any view SYSCAT.xxxxxAUTH will show the authorizations for that particular area.

Examples include SYSCAT.DBAUTH is authorizations at the database level. SYSCAT.ROLEAUTH is authorizations to roles. SYSCAT.INDEXAUTH is authorizations for indexes, etc.